# Time calculations in Rails where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, squeel

I'm trying to make some time calculations in where statement. I would like to select offers which life time has already past.

```
select_offers = Offer.where { (published_time + life_time) < DateTime.now }
```

It doesn't throw any error but it also doesn't return objects. I'm using squeel gem. What is the best approach to this?

Comment: What is the datatype of your `life_time`?

Comment: It's `int` but in view `published_time + life_time` works fine and add days. In where statemet life_time.days doesn't work.

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct magnitudes? I believe when rails compares two date types that are in different formats, it will convert the dates to seconds since epoch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `life_time` is the number of days for which offer is valid.

```
select_offers = Offer.where(["DATE_ADD(published_time, INTERVAL life_time DAY) <  ? " , DateTime.now ]
```

Ref:- [`DATE_ADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) function of mysql